# Using a NestedScrollView and supplying a ScrollController downstream to a ListView

Tags: flutter

I have a `NestedScrollView` which works well to AutoHide the AppBar (one feature I want) when I use `SliverAppBar`. Where I am running into problems, is I use `ListView.Builder` as one of the body components downstream that I need apply its own `ScrollController` to (or seems I need to apply it here). This conflicts with the `NestedScrollView` and I lose the autohide of the appbar that is conveniently handled by the `NestedScrollView` and `SliverAppBar`.

If I attach the `ScrollController` on the `NestedScrollView` Then it only tracks scroll position up to an offset of 80.0 and after that, with a longer ListView I am unable to properly animateTo as I can with the ScrollController attached directly to the `ListView.Builder`.

Here is a snippet/sudo code of my implementation:

```
new Scaffold(
    drawer: ...,
    body: new NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return [
                new SliverAppBar(
                    title: new Text('Title'),
                    floating: true,
                    snap: true
                )
            ]
        }
        body: new Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
                new PageView(
                    children: <Widget>[
                        new PageView1(implements ListViewBuilder),
                        new PageView2(implements ListView),
                        new PageView3(implements ListView),
                    ]
                    controller: _pageController,
                ),
                new FloatingActionButton
            ]
        )
    )
)

class PageView1 extends StateFulWidget {
    ...//Builder return scrollable with max offset of 2000.0
        return new ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: itemBuilder,
        itemCount: objects.length,
        controller: _scrollController,
        );
    ...

    @override
    void initState{
        scrollController = new scrollController();
        scrollController.animateTo(800.0, ....);
    }
}
```

The nice part about this is the PageView2 and 3 behave nicely, with the autohide of the app bar on scroll behavior as I am not creating ScrollControllers there. But, PageView1 behaves incorrectly and autoHide of the appbar breaks. But, I really want to be able to animateTo correctly and am unable to do so without placing the controller directly on the ListViewBuilder.

Any thoughts on a better implementation that would help me achieve this?

UPDATE: I have updated my implementation to more closely follow the NestedScrollView documentation. But, with no luck. It seems the addition of the ScrollController on the NestedScrollView only tracks the position of the SliverAppBar, and ScrollController.jumpTo or animateTo only jump to a maximum of the AppBar (offset 80)

I worked it out.. This is not how I expected it to work at all. I moved my SliverList into the headerSliverBuilder and it works the way I want it to. I took the cue to do so from this NestedScrollView example gist: https://gist.github.com/collinjackson/2bc6697d31e6b94ada330ef5e818a36f

Comment: The above example is only paasing th Parent controller to the child page,and just works only for 180 pixles,as i scroll the child list,its not updating anymore,Sharing your Code[ after removing your credential codes] will be helpful

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I have the exact problem. I want to control the inner scrollable widget under the `NestedScrollView`?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the [NestedScrollViewExample](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html):

Change your list view to SliverList or SliverFixedExtentList and Wrap it inside a safe area and a CustomScrollView:

```
return SafeArea(
  top: false,
  bottom: false,
  child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) => CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      return SliverFixedExtentList(
        itemExtent: 100.0,
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (BuildContext context, int i) => ChildWidget(items[i]),
          childCount: items.length,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )),
);
```

Comment: I did try using a SliverList ... But not inside a SafeArea. I'll give that a go.

Comment: I tried. :( Still just getting the outer scroll position from my controller.

Comment: Did you wrap the SliverList inside a CustomScrollView?

Comment: Yep. If I move the `SliverList` into the `NestedScrollView` -> `headerSliverBuilder` the offset indeed can be captured as the you scroll beyond the AppBar. I have not added back in the JumpTo/AnimateTo at that point. But since I can now at least see the controller has position on the Scrollable content I expect it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I met with the same problem and here is my solution. You can add a key to NestedScrollView and use it to access the inner CustomScrollView/ListViewcontroller of the tab, you only need to add the ScrollController to NestedScrollView

```
final GlobalKey<NestedScrollViewState> documentsNestedKey = GlobalKey();

void initState() {
_scrollController = ScrollController();
_tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
_tabController.addListener(() {
  setState(() {});
});

// Tabs Pagination
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
  documentsNestedKey.currentState!.innerController.addListener(() {
    if (documentsNestedKey.currentState!.innerController.positions.last.atEdge) {
      if (documentsNestedKey.currentState!.innerController.positions.last.pixels != 0) {
        if (_tabController.index == 0) {
          context.read<DeclarationsBloc>().add(const FetchDeclarationsEvent());
        } else {
          context.read<TasksBloc>().add(const FetchTasksEvent());
        }
      }
    }
  });
});

super.initState();
```

}

```
return SafeArea(
  child: NestedScrollView(
    key: documentsNestedKey,
    controller: _scrollController,
    floatHeaderSlivers: true,
    headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
      SliverOverlapAbsorber(
        handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
        sliver: SliverAppBar(
          backgroundColor: theme.background,
          floating: true,
          pinned: true,
          forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            background: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 11),
                Padding(
                  padding: responsiveUtil.getHorizontalPadding(),
                  child: SearchWithFilter(
                    searchController: widget.searchController,
                    currentMenuIndex: 3,
                    onSearch: (text) {},
                    onSearchClear: () {},
                    onFilterTap: widget.onFilterTap,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          bottom: DeclarationsTabBar(
            tabController: _tabController,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
    body: TabBarView(
      controller: _tabController,
      children: [
        MyDeclarationsTab(searchController: widget.searchController),
        TasksTab(searchController: widget.searchController),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else getting to this page, the following code worked for me.
After searching for couple days, found an issue ticket, under which one of the comment describes logical solution with helper class.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/118713#issuecomment-1416505982

```
/// https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/118713#issuecomment-1416505982    

/// A scroll controller subordinate to a parent controller, which
/// [createScrollPosition]s via the parent and attaches/detaches its positions
/// from the parent. This is useful for creating nested scroll controllers
/// for widgets with scrollbars that can actuate a parent scroll controller.
class SubordinateScrollController extends ScrollController {
  SubordinateScrollController(
    this.parent, {
    String subordinateDebugLabel = 'subordinate',
  }) : super(
          debugLabel: parent.debugLabel == null
              ? null
              : '${parent.debugLabel}/$subordinateDebugLabel',
          initialScrollOffset: parent.initialScrollOffset,
          keepScrollOffset: parent.keepScrollOffset,
        );
  final ScrollController parent;
  // Although some use cases might seem to be simplified if parent were made
  // settable, we can't really do this because scroll positions are owned by
  // Scrollables rather than the scroll controller, so the scroll view is
  // responsible for transferring positions from one controller to another. If
  // we were to try to do the transfer here, we would end up trying to dispose
  // of positions that Scrollables may still be holding on to.

  @override
  ScrollPosition createScrollPosition(
    ScrollPhysics physics,
    ScrollContext context,
    ScrollPosition? oldPosition,
  ) =>
      parent.createScrollPosition(physics, context, oldPosition);

  @override
  void attach(ScrollPosition position) {
    super.attach(position);
    parent.attach(position);
  }

  @override
  void detach(ScrollPosition position) {
    parent.detach(position);
    super.detach(position);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    for (final position in positions) {
      parent.detach(position);
    }

    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

This helper class sort of allows any of the nested children of NestedScrollView to coordinate with the ScrollPosition set by the NestedScrollView  (which maintains as member an accessible outerController for the appbar and an innerController for the body and synchronizes them).
Manages this by having a separate (!) (Subordinate)ScrollController. This controller has to be given to the ListView / GridView as controller. Also SubordinateScrollController has to receive the NestedScrollView's innerController as parameter. For this I used this code, but you could achive it with GlobalKey as well.

```
 GridView.builder(controller: SubordinateScrollController(context
        .findAncestorStateOfType<NestedScrollViewState>()!
        .innerController, ...);
```

If you don't use the helper class you will receive error messages like this one and having scroll bar disappeared:

```
 Another exception was thrown: The provided ScrollController is currently attached to more than one ScrollPosition
```

There is also an interesting article on how NestedScrollView works:
https://medium.com/@jdavifranco/nestedscrollview-widget-explained-flutter-4145e42faee0